# number and size of slices in a chart with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts, circles

In this chart I can determine the number of slices, but not the size of slices. How to determine the size of each slice ? Thanks for your help

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=30cm,paperwidth=35cm,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6] % pour rester dans la page
% center
\path  (0,0) coordinate(A);
% circles
\foreach \rr in {12,...,25}{
  \draw  (A) circle (\rr);
}
\def\pp{4} % nb of slices
% rays
\foreach \aa in {1,...,\pp}{
  \draw ($(A)+(\aa/\pp*180:12)$) --  ($(A)+(\aa/\pp*180:24)$); 

}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution that equally slices the circle evenly, given the number of slices which is defined as `\pp` by the OP.

**Update:** The OP wants to divide the pie with percentage being given. In this demonstration.  The percentage is assumed to be 30,40,20,10 respectively for the 4 slices. To draw them, the `foreach` takes [0,30,70,90,100].

[image]

New Code for percentage being known.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[papers=30cm,paperwidth=35cm,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2] % pour rester dans la page
% center
\path  (0,0) coordinate(A);
% circles
\foreach \rr in {12,...,25}{
  \draw  (A) circle (\rr);
}
\def\pp{4} % nb of slices
% Assume the percentage is 30,40,20,10 respectively for the 4 slice
\foreach \aa in {0,30,70,90,100}{
\draw ($(A)+({\aa*36/10}:12)$) --  ($(A)+({\aa*36/10}:25)$); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Old Code for equally sliced.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[papers=30cm,paperwidth=35cm,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2] % pour rester dans la page
% center
\path  (0,0) coordinate(A);
% circles
\foreach \rr in {12,...,25}{
  \draw  (A) circle (\rr);
}
\def\pp{10} % nb of slices
% rays
\foreach \aa in {1,...,\pp}{
\draw ($(A)+({\aa*360/\pp}:12)$) --  ($(A)+({\aa*360/\pp}:25)$); 

}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What I ask is about dividing the chart in a number of parts with the size expressed by percent.  Example 3 parts with 75%, 15%, 10%.